# Sound Design in Argentina Documentary

Tags: sound-design, argentina, documentary, collaboration, graduate

Hey everyone! I'm working on my graduate thesis. It's a documentary about Sound Design in Argentina and right now I'm on the pre-production process.

I'm looking for any historical data/info/multimedia to include in my movie.

I also plan to interview sound designers who had worked or are working for Film/TV in Argentina.

**All suggestions and info are VERY welcome**, and of course, let me know if you know someone you think is relevant in the industry to be interviewed!! (Directors and Producers with deep interest in sound design are also welcome).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Fabián Bielinsky.  He was a legend in Argentina, and worked on some classics.  You can't go wrong with starting on him.

Comment: As you said, Bielinsky's films were really important for Argentina and very innovative and fresh. Pitifully, he passed away 4 years ago and due to the character of my documentary based on interviews I can't take action on your suggestion. But again, great movies from him and thanks for your input!

Comment: Although you can't conduct your own personal interview with Mr. Bielinsky, don't overlook the possibility of older interviews he may have done with other people, or print articles for that matter.

Comment: Also interviewing sound designers who were close to him.

Answer (score 1):

Hi!

I recommend you Gustavo Costantini. He is more theoretician than sound designer, but does both... Despite of his not-so-easy-character as you will discover on your own, i definetely recommend him ;) I'm sure he will know to guide you...

Good luck
and looking forward to see your docu done!

s

[image]

Comment: Hey Marty, thanks for your recommendation! In fact, I was in his studio two weeks ago. I must disagree with you about his character/temper: he was very kind with me and he gave me an extense approach about sound design, near an hour of raw material. Gustavo has a really huge theory background knowledge. He has a lot of synths and diverse hardware, and also A LOT of books. The meeting was very inspiring and content-rich. I posted a snapshot of the interview with Gustavo Costantini in your answer, because I cannot do it on a comment. Best regards, Alan.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier this year I did the sound for a documentary taking place in Buenos Aires. I visited the city last year and it's an amazing place - recorded lots of noisy, gritty, vivid ambiences.

One of my favorite filmmakers at the moment is actually Argentinian: Lucrecia Martel - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucrecia_Martel - all her movies are really fascinating with extraordinary soundtracks which are very evocative and often make use of background ambiences in extremely creative ways. Check it out. I think her sound designer is called Guido Berenblum - exceptionally talented.

Comment: I'm going to interview Guido Beremblum this month. Gustavo Costantini had recommended me to meet him a lot, and I think it will be a good way to reach Lucrecia Martel too. His work in "La Niña Santa" was terrific! Martel's film's sound design is probably the best in Argentina.